# "wouldn’t hesitate for a minute vs wouldn’t hesitate a minute"

Tags: phrase-meaning

> If I were you, I **wouldn’t hesitate for a minute**.
>
> If I were you, I **wouldn’t hesitate a minute**.

If I understand correctly, the first sentence means "I wouldn’t hesitate during one minute", but the second one - "I wouldn’t hesitate even one minute". Do we speak about the same time for a decision making? It seems the second sentence says about a faster decision making. And I guess the second sentence says  it with more emphasis. Is it a correct interpretation or is something missed?

Comment: They are both the same meaning, same urgency.  A greater emphasis on how quickly the decision should be made could be achieved by decreasing the interval of time, such as "I wouldn't hesitate for even a second if I were you".

Comment: Yes they both mean the same thing **If I were you I'd do it now**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence is quite clear, because the preposition "for" is often followed by a measure of time to indicate the duration of an event.

The second sentence lacks a preposition, so its meaning must be inferred. Nominal phrases (such as "a minute") can be used adverbially, and when one represents a measure of time, it often indicates the duration of an event. Therefore, the natural interpretation of the second sentence is exactly the same as the interpretation of the first. There is no difference in emphasis.